# How to create a subdomain Hosted Zone using Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-cloudformation

I'd like to create a Route53 Hosted Zone for a subdomain and `NS` record to parent domain.

Let's say I have:

```
example.com
```

and I want a hosted zone for subdomain:

```
build.example.com
```

Hosted Zone creation works:

```
ClusterHostedZone:
  Type: "AWS::Route53::HostedZone"
  Properties:
    Name: !Ref DomainName
    HostedZoneConfig:
      Comment: Managed by Cloud Formation
    HostedZoneTags:
      - Key: KubernetesCluster
        Value: !Ref KubernetesCluster
```

Delegating responsibility for the subdomain don't:

```
ParentHostedZoneClusterRecord:
  Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSet"
  Properties:
    Name: !Ref DomainName
    Comment: Managed by Cloud Formation
    HostedZoneId: !Ref ParentHostedZoneID
    TTL: 30
    Type: NS
    ResourceRecords: !GetAtt ClusterHostedZone.NameServers
```

This is not implemented and I don't know **how to get this information**:

```
ResourceRecords: !GetAtt ClusterHostedZone.NameServers
```

Is this simple feature just missing in Cloud Formation?

Comment: Would RecordSetGroup be a solution? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordsetgroup.html

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see how that would help. Could you elaborate?

Comment: am I correct in understanding that you want to associate a bunch of aliases under your hosted zone?

Comment: As is stated in the title, I'm creating a hosted zone for a subdomain, a very common user case

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edit but I still don't understand your question completely. Is the `example.com` Hosted Zone in Route53, or is it somewhere else? If Route53, what is your use-case for needing a separate hosted zone for `build.example.com` with matching name servers, rather than simply using the `example.com` Hosted Zone?  Also, in the example code, what are the values of `DomainName` (`build.example.com`, or `example.com`, or something else) and `ParentHostedZoneID`? You might be able to accomplish what you need with DelegationSets via Custom Resources but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: I was aiming for this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working for my, maybe your template is not working because you do not specify `DependsOn` and resources are not created in order.

```
stagingHostedZone:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::HostedZone'
    Properties:
        HostedZoneConfig:
            Comment: Hosted zone for staging environment
        Name: staging.example.com

nsRootHostedZoneRecordSet:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::RecordSet'
    Properties:
        HostedZoneId: Z25*********
        Name: staging.example.com.
        Type: NS
        TTL: '900'
        ResourceRecords: !GetAtt stagingHostedZone.NameServers
    DependsOn:
        stagingHostedZone
```

Comment: look like AWS added features since January

Comment: This fails with "Attribute 'NameServers' does not exist".

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-hostedzone.html#aws-resource-route53-hostedzone-return-values-fn--getatt) show a GetAtt call should work.

Answer (score 2):

I confirmed with an AWS employee it was not possible around January 2017.

Even with a custom lambda [it was not possible until April](https://web.archive.org/web/20170425192629/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-type) due to:

> <s>In AWS CloudFormation, you can't create records of type NS or SOA.</s>

Now it looks like the [behavior is different](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-recordset.html#cfn-route53-recordset-type):

> Specifically, you can't create or delete NS or SOA records for the root domain of your hosted zone, but you can create them for subdomains to delegate.

Getting name servers from a hosted zone is [now possible],
 I've tested it.(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-hostedzone.html#w2ab2c21c10d825c11)

The only limitation I was not able to overcome was cross-account Hosted Zones relations/modifications, but it should be doable with enough CF/Lambda magic.

Comment: This is false. The link above does NOT say you can't create NS records, it specifically says you CAN create them for subdomains: "In AWS CloudFormation, you cannot modify the NS and SOA records for a hosted zone created automatically by Amazon Route 53. Specifically, you can't create or delete NS or SOA records for the root domain of your hosted zone, but you can create them for subdomains to delegate. For example, for hosted zone mydomain.net, you cannot create an NS record for mydomain.net but you can create an NS record for nnnn.mydomain.net for delegation."

Comment: If you could provide an example stack, that would be appreciated

Comment: Have a look at this stack: https://github.com/ConradIrwin/aws-name-server/blob/master/cloudformation-template.json

Comment: @Fo. this is a entirely different use case, in your example the NS record values are taken from EC2 instance, that's not applicable in my use case

Comment: @Fo. second thing is that it looks like the implementation and documentation changed slightly, I'll edit to correct that

Answer (score 1):

To add a Hosted Zone for a subdomain, you should be able to create it similar to the existing Hosted Zone described, just changing the `Name` property to the subdomain.

However, based on your question it sounds like you're actually trying to add a Record Set for a subdomain (so `build.[DomainName]` resolves to your cluster), not a separate Hosted Zone.

To add a Record Set for a subdomain, you want to specify `'build.[DomainName]'` as the Name of your subdomain's RecordSet, and use an [`A` record](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#AFormat) specifying the target IP address for your subdomain (or a [`CNAME`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#CNAMEFormat) specifying the 'canonical' domain name), not an [`NS` record](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#NSFormat):

```
ParentHostedZoneClusterRecord:
  Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSet"
  Properties:
    Name:
      Fn::Join: [".", ["build", !Ref DomainName]]
    Comment: Managed by Cloud Formation
    HostedZoneId: !Ref ParentHostedZoneID
    TTL: 30
    Type: A
    ResourceRecords: [!Ref KubernetesClusterIp]
```

Comment: I want to add `NS` record to parent domain, Hosted Zone creation is simple, it's the parent-to-child delegation that I can't do with CF